# Jquery ui slider handle on over display hand

Tags: jquery-ui

I have a jquery UI Slider. When i take my mouse over the slider handle  it should display a hand pointer.It's not displaying right now. How can i display hand pointer..?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<style type="text/css">
    .ui-slider .ui-slider-handle
    {
        cursor: pointer;
    }
</style>
```